# <c:if> call @PostConstruct in @ViewScoped bean in ajax calls. - JSF 2.1

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I spot an issue in my project which `<c:if>` is reloading the `@PostConsturct` again and again when invoke `ajax` calls.
I use `weblogic 12C`

When I remove below line, page works perfectly without reloading the bean.

```
<c:if test="#{planOverlay.selectedItem.cardOnly}"><f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="No Contract"/></c:if>
```

user suppose to select the check box. So whenever user click on this check the `@ViewScoped` bean's `@PostConstruct` method is calling.

Below is my check box code.

```
<td>
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{plan.checked}">
     <f:ajax listener="#{planOverlay.selectPlan}" render=":overlayForm:myTable"/>
  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

1. Why  reload the bean when ever have an ajax call to bean?
2. Can I replace the  with  ?

I am using weblogic 12C and it's jsf version is `1.0.0.0_2-1`. It says this issue has been fixed in jsf `2.1.18`.

Comment: @BalusC    I use `weblogic 12 C`. In another post you mentioned that the default jsf version is `2.1.20`.  This issue has been fixed in 2.1.18 it seems.

Comment: Do you still have that offending Mojarra 2.0.2 in the runtime classpath?

Comment: @BalusC    I have `glassfish.jsf_1.0.0.0_2-1-5.jar` in the `../oracle/product/wls12110/modules`.  Which means I am not using `2.1.18`  and therefore I face this issue?